# Как закодировать данные в map?

Tags: flutter, dart

Необходимо закодировать значения в map (не переводя в строку).
Изначально данные в map выглядят так:

user: Admin 1

Необходимо получить:

user: Admin%201

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то так:

```
import 'dart:core';

void main() {
  Map<String, String> map = <String, String>{'user': 'Admin 1'};
  
  print(map.map((k,v) => MapEntry(k, Uri.encodeComponent(v))));
}
```